# UINavigationController native-looking push interactive transition

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

When using UINavigationController in iOS7, you can interactively swipe from the left edge back to the previous view controller.  How can I add an identical swipe from the right edge to push a view controller, like Mobile Safari does?

Comment: Gesture recognizer with push action?

Comment: Yes.  But I'm curious if anyone has figured out the parameters that will match Apple's built in ones?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` with right edge as allowed edges. When the gesture is detected, use an interactive percent-driven push to create the same effect. If you wish to create something more advanced, you can also add a shadow view and make its alpha dependent on the percent of completion.